# Notepad++ Regex assistance needed

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following example:

`assert(apply_patch_check("/system/app/ApplicationsProvider.odex", "31bdc8cc9a131131f97a931933723c0fa6c786ba", "c996ebe1ab91e780dc9b6a41c18214c633413dc4"));
set_progress(0.000153);`

`assert(apply_patch_check("/system/app/AtciService.odex", "09003fce87c178afb603f4ad7fd9db2e612d0648", "aa28dfd656fd12f38f904f85f85f432a822e7719"));
set_progress(0.000386);`

what I need is only:

```
/system/app/ApplicationsProvider.odex

/system/app/AtciService.odex
```

How to do that with notepad++

Comment: Show what you have tried so far please

Answer (score 2):

```
Find what: ^[^"]*"([^"]*).*$
Replace with: \1
```

Basically use first and second quotation mark to extract text that is in between them.

Comment: It's better to use $1 for replacing string. Nevertheless +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too

Find what: `(sys.*dex)|.\s?`  or `.*(sys.*dex).*\W`
Replace with: `$1`